# Rails API using token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, curl

I have a rails API backend with a gem called [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) .
On client side i use an angular app (from an other domain) with a module called ng-token-auth (by the same author).

From client side, i can log in and keep session alive. i use localStorage to store token.

Then i would like to post things from client on server only if member is logged in.

i have a post model and a comment model working fine on rails. 
When i send a comment on a post, from client side or with Curl, its fine.
when i add a filter like : "before_action :authenticate_member!" on my controller on rails, i get a 401 response. like if member was not logged in.

Is it because the token is not send with the post request ?
or a server side issue ? misconfiguration on rails ?
Is there a way to test to post something with curl ?

something like this but with the token: ?

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:5000/v1/posts/MY_POST_ID/comments' -d '{"name":"author","body":"test body"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

(this is working without the before_action filter on rails)

Comment: I ended this by reading [this article](http://blog.sundaycoding.com/blog/2015/04/04/token-authentication-with-tiddle/) and stop using devise_token_auth  (few month ago)